# pipe(), fork() and for loops

Tags: pipe, c

I am writing a program for an assignment where I am supposed to create multiple child processes from a parent, and then continually pipe information to their standard inputs to run a text-based game (and then get info from the children through their standard outputs, but I am going to sort that out later after I sort out stdin).

The issue I am having is that I can either get the first line of input to go to all the children and then no others, or get any lines I want to go to one. Unfortunately I can't post my code for this section because my university is very strict about posting code samples, but I can provide a basic outline below.

Parent:

```
for all players:
    make a pipe between player and parent
    fork()
    if child:
        close write end, redirect read to stdin, close read end
        set up parameters for player process, then execute player program
    else if parent:
        close read end
        write stuff to write end of pipe
        wait for process to be done
```

The child basically just reads from stdin and uses the information to make some variables, etc etc.

Would you provide suggestions of things to check or try.

Comment: You would end up with an array of pipes, one element connecting the parent with a particular child. They can't share a single pipe.

Comment: @Kusalananda thank you so much, I figured that's what I would have to do, just wanted some clarification.

Comment: Even though you can't post your specific code, you should be able to create a [mcve] that demonstrates this part of the problem, without being your actual program.